# PhpStorm multi line if() statement auto format

Tags: php, phpstorm, code-formatting

Let's assume we use PHP and hard wrap at 80 in our project.

I want this:

```php
if ($text === 'testTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest' || $text === 'testTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest' || $text === 'testTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest') {
    $text = 'test';
}
```

to become this:

```php
if ($text === 'testTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest' 
    || $text === 'testTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest'
    || $text === 'testTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest')
{
    $text = 'test';
}
```

Is there any way to configure PhpStorm so this formatting is performed when <kbd>Ctrl + Alt + L</kbd> is pressed?

I've tried some options in *Settings - Editor - Code Style - PHP - Wrapping and Braces - 'if()' statement*, but it didn't help.

Seems like I'm doing something wrong. Please, help.

Comment: File a feature request at Jetbrains.

Comment: Please export your Code Style in XML format and share the file (so it can be tested locally). For me, PSR12 based schema formats your code sample as you want.

Comment: Try the following: `Braces placement | Other` => `Next line`; `Binary expressions` => `Wrap if long`; `Binary expressions | Operation sign on next line` => enabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, there's a [statement in PSR-12](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/#51-if-elseif-else) on how you should format such type of long expressions. In our case it should be like this:

```
if (
    $text === 'testTestTestTestTestTestTestTest'
    || $text2 === 'testTestTestTestTestTestTestTestTest'
    || $text3 === 'testTestTestTestTestTestTest'
) {
    $text = 'test';
}
```

To make PhpStorm format it like that:

1. Go to `File | Settings | Editor | Code Style | PHP`
2. On the right side hit `"Set from..." -> PSR-12`
3. Go to `Wrapping and Braces` tab
4. Set `Binary expressions = Wrap if long` and checkmark to `Operation sign on next line`
5. On the same tab at the `'if()' statement` section check both `New line before first element` and `New line before last element`.